# Double nested function in R

Tags: r, logical-operators, nested-for-loop

I have the following code:

```
 mdf[,c(4)]<- mdf$`CLAVE EMISORA` %in% BMV[[1]]$`CLAVE EMISORA`
 mdf[,c(5)]<- mdf$`CLAVE EMISORA` %in% BMV[[2]]$`CLAVE EMISORA`
 ...............................................................
 mdf[,c(13)]<- mdf$`CLAVE EMISORA` %in% BMV[[10]]$`CLAVE EMISORA`
```

It basically does a logical test of whether the content of each row of a column is contained within the column of a data frame inside list. The result is a logical test along a series of columns telling me where its contained, for that I have assigned columns 4-13 as a dichotomous variable of the presence or absence of each row in each list. But now I want to reduce the code and instead of mapping the results to different columns I want to use a single column with levels (1-10) where each level will be equal to the i list.
I've tried with a nested for loop but it doesn't do the job.

```
for (i in mdf$`CLAVE EMISORA`){
  for (x in 1:10)
  if (mdf$`CLAVE EMISORA` %in% BMV[[x]]$`CLAVE EMISORA`)
    mdf$`SECTOR` <- x
  }
```

Example database:

```
   `CLAVE EMISORA` `RAZON SOCIAL`                            SECTOR
   <chr>           <chr>                                     <lgl> 
 1 AC              ARCA CONTINENTAL, S.A.B. DE C.V.          NA    
 2 ACCELSA         ACCEL, S.A.B. DE C.V.                     NA    
 3 ACTINVR         CORPORACION ACTINVER, S.A.B. DE C.V.      NA    
 4 AEROMEX         GRUPO AEROMÉXICO, S.A.B. DE C.V.          NA    
 5 AGRIEXP         AGRO INDUSTRIAL EXPORTADORA, S.A. DE C.V. NA    
 6 AGUA            GRUPO ROTOPLAS, S.A.B. DE C.V.            NA    
 7 AHMSA           ALTOS HORNOS DE MEXICO, S.A. DE C.V.      NA    
 8 ALEATIC         ALEATICA, S.A.B. DE C.V.                  NA    
 9 ALFA            ALFA, S.A.B. DE C.V.                      NA    
10 ALPEK           ALPEK, S.A.B. DE C.V.                     NA
```

Example list

```
CLAVE EMISORA RAZON SOCIAL
1   3391      TSURUHA HOLDINGS, INC.
2   4911      SHISEIDO COMPANY, LIMITED
3   ABEV      AMBEV S.A.
4   AC        ARCA CONTINENTAL, S.A.B. DE C.V.
5   ACBE      AC BEBIDAS, S. DE R.L. DE C.V.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you would want is to simply iterate over your 10 indices like this and perform your operation.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    mdf[,i + 3]<- mdf$`CLAVE EMISORA` %in% BMV[[i]]$`CLAVE EMISORA`
}
```

You could replace the `i+3` with some programatic way of getting nicer column names if you wanted to.

Comment: My god... I actually wrote a similar snippet except for the coma, this makes me depressed.